# Wordpress Custom widget UPDATE function and array

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I created a custom category widget for our wordpress blog, but need some help as some of the options are little messed up.

The update function create an array, but not in the way I need. Here is an example of such array:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Blog Categories
    [cat_visibility] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
        )

    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 9
        )

    [URL_term_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 9
            [4] => 10
        )

    [URL_title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Category 1
            [1] => Category 2
            [2] => Category 3
            [3] => Category 4
            [4] => Category 5
        )

)
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance[ 'title' ] = strip_tags( $new_instance[ 'title' ] );
    $instance[ 'cat_visibility' ] = $new_instance[ 'cat_visibility' ];
    $instance[ 'categories' ] = $new_instance['categories'];
    $instance[ 'URL_term_id' ] = $new_instance[ 'URL_term_id' ];
    $instance[ 'URL_title' ] = $new_instance['URL_title'];
    return $instance;
}
```

And at last, here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 1
            [term_id] => 1
            [title] => Category 1
            [cat_visibility] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 
            [term_id] => 7
            [title] => Category 2
            [cat_visibility] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 
            [term_id] => 8
            [title] => Category 3
            [cat_visibility] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 9
            [term_id] => 9
            [title] => Category 4
            [cat_visibility] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 
            [term_id] => 10
            [title] => Category 5
            [cat_visibility] => 
        )

)
```

So far I have tried converting the initial array with the following code:

```
$new_object = [];
        for($i=0;$i<count($URL_term_id);$i++){
            array_push($new_object,
                array(
                    "category_id"=>$cat_id[$i],
                    "term_id"=>$URL_term_id[$i],
                    "title"=>$URL_title_id[$i],
                    "cat_visibility"=>$cat_visibility[$i]
                )
            );
        }
```

It created almost what I need, but because of the difference in keys does not create the array I need.

Here is what I get from it:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 1
            [term_id] => 1
            [title] => Category 1
            [cat_visibility] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 9
            [term_id] => 7
            [title] => Category 2
            [cat_visibility] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 
            [term_id] => 8
            [title] => Category 3
            [cat_visibility] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 
            [term_id] => 9
            [title] => Category 4
            [cat_visibility] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [category_id] => 
            [term_id] => 10
            [title] => Category 5
            [cat_visibility] => 
        )

)
```

Any advice and help is appreciated.